# Add a disk into volume group

Tags: lvm, xfs

I want to extend a filesystem mounted as `/a01` with XFS filesystem on an Oracle Linux 8.x system.

I have an existing virtual disk with 50Gb  `/dev/sdc` partitioned with `fdisk` as `/dev/sdc1`.

My current volume group:

```
# pvs 
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  ol        lvm2 a--  146.00g 4.00m
  /dev/sdb1  oracle_vg lvm2 a--   99.00g    0
  /dev/sdc1  oracle_vg lvm2 a--  <50.00g    0

# vgs 
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ol          1   8   0 wz--n- 146.00g 4.00m
  oracle_vg   2   1   0 wz--n-  99.00g    0

# lvs
  LV            VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home          ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  root          ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  root00        ol        -wi-ao---- 100.00g
  swap          ol        -wi-ao----  16.00g
  tmp           ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  var           ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  var_log_audit ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  var_tmp       ol        -wi-ao----   5.00g
  lv_a01        oracle_vg -wi-a-----  99.00g
```

Output of `pvdisplay -m /dev/sdc1`:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               oracle_vg
  PV Size               <50.00 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               99.00 GiB
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               8rmxdf-zv2M-SkRQ-YNtt-Y6jK-3Afa-73PrpJ

  --- Physical Segments ---
```

Why can't I extend my `lv` and my `vg`?
Thanks for the help.

---

I removed the disk from the `vg`:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc1
  Physical volume "/dev/sdc1" successfully created.

# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  ol        lvm2 a--  146.00g   4.00m
  /dev/sdb1  oracle_vg lvm2 a--   99.00g      0
  /dev/sdc1            lvm2 ---  <50.00g <50.00g
# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ol          1   8   0 wz--n- 146.00g 4.00m
  oracle_vg   1   1   0 wz--n-  99.00g    0
# vgextend oracle_vg /dev/sdc1
  Volume group "oracle_vg" successfully extended
# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ol          1   8   0 wz--n- 146.00g 4.00m
  oracle_vg   2   1   0 wz--n-  99.00g    0
```

Comment: It seems something has been allocated to /dev/sdc1 -- there's no free space left on it. Did you already extend lv_a01 with the 50G of space from /dev/sdc1, or was it already 99G in size? The output of `pvdisplay -m /dev/sdc1` (in an [edit] to your question) could show what's been allocated to that disk.

Comment: @JeffSchaller i didnot extendlv ,  the only cmd i performed is extendvg

Comment: This is odd that the disk appears to be 50G but reports no free extents. Was it perhaps allocated, assigned to the VG, then removed and reallocated?

Comment: i follow the same procedure for extending a vg , but the issue persist .

Comment: It appears (to me) as though another LV in oracle_vg is automatically expanding to take the free space.  Can you compare the sizes of the other LV's in that VG before & after?